# TypeError: edit_undo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

This is my edited code:

```
from tkinter import *

class UI:
   def __init__(self):
      self.root = Tk()
      self.text= Text(self.root)
      self.text.pack()
      self.text.bind("<Return>", self.entry.edit_undo)
      self.text.mainloop()

UI()
```

and when I run it it runs normally but, when `diff.node_root.bind()` is triggered, it shows an error that says `TypeError: edit_undo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. can anybody help me please?

Comment: the `diff`is the represent the instance of the class like `self`, but i use a different name :)

Comment: That's better. Now can you please show what is `edit_undo`?

Comment: edit_undo is a built in method within Text widget class [here's the information about it](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#more)

Comment: but i still dont get anything :(

Comment: Please see my answer below, but also please read about [mre]. Your code is still not reproducible. You use `self.entry` but never define it

Answer (score 1):

The functions that you pass to `bind` (event handlers) [are expected to take one `event` argument](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html). [`edit_undo`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html) **doesn't take any arguments** (except for `self` that is...).

If you are not interested in the actual `event`, you can instead pass a function that ignores it, something like:

```
self.text.bind("<Return>", lambda e: self.entry.edit_undo())
```

Comment: Yes i've already fix it but, its still show an error `_tkinter.TclError: nothing to undo`

Comment: Well with that I can't really help as it depends on the state of your text widget. You will have to make sure this actually works only when there is something to undo